# css clearfix behavior not the same for firefox and chrome

Tags: html, css, css-float, clearfix

i am using this class for css clearfix on a div which has a calculated width of 0, but has content of width x in it.

```
.clearfix {
 *zoom: 1;
 &:before,
 &:after {
   display: table;
   content: "";
 }
 &:after {
   clear: both;
 }
}
```

What is happening is that **in chrome** after i use this class,  the div takes the width of its content. **But in firefox**, the div takes the width of its parent.

Shouldn't the behavior be that the div takes the width of its content in both browsers?
What can be the issue?

Comment: _OT: I will never understand why people use these extremely ugly kind of clearfixes …_

Comment: please suggest one then

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle or at least a complete code example?

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't interfere with your other styles, you can use `overflow: hidden;` to force a container to expand for floated content, etc.

See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mBSCj/ which works in all major browsers.

Comment: As long as you don't have overflowing content (think drop menu), this is a perfectly fine way of going about clearing floats.

Comment: @cimmanon Yeah I've tripped myself up a couple of times when I forgot I was using it, but I've generally found this to be the most concise and consistent method, particularly because it doesn't require extra elements or pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 1):

There is one other method for clearing floats without using additional markup.  It predates the *micro clearfix* by quite a few years.

http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```